# new records being saved but empty in mysql, but the email with info does get sent to me fine, but not the user

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

(updated again)

Am now getting an error message....

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO hcontact (FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Address,EmailAddress,Country,Comments,SubscribetoMailingList)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
(line 23)     $stmt->bindParam("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $address, $emailaddress, $country, $comments, $mailinglist);
```

Error message I am receiving in Dreamweaver is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bindParam() in /homepages/**/d*******/htdocs/action_page.php on line 23

(Updated)
trying this again.. I changed it to look like this.. but I don't know what a backtic is.  I looked it up but couldn't find it in w3 schools search..

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO hcontact (FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,Address,EmailAddress,Country,Comments,SubscribetoMailingList)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $address, $emailaddress, $country, $comments, $mailinglist);


if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $connect->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. <br> Newly inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
echo "<br>";

// define variables and set to empty values
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
$mailinglist = $_POST['mailinglist'];
$stmt->execute();
```

(first question)
I have an html simple contact form (with the trimmings and error message) and a php form to take the info and dump it into my mysql database.

I have been able to get it to send me the email as it should, and create a new record with an ID increment and date timestamp as it should..

here is where I run into problems .. I think...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO hcontact 
    (
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    PhoneNumber, 
    Address,  
    EmailAddress, 
    Country, 
    Comments, 
    SubscribetoMailingList)
VALUES (
    'firstname', 
    'lastname', 
    'phonenumber', 
    'address', 
    'emailaddress', 
    'country', 
    'comments', 
    'mailinglist')";
```

if I write the values as such 'firstname', 'lastname' with the single quotes.. then the info gets entered into the database... but not entirely correctly... it just shows: first name, lastname,  but not the user inputted info, just the words firstname, lastname which are in the single quotes.

If I change the values to be written without the single quotes, then nothing shows up when a user enters data.

The id is incremented with each new record, and the date and time stamp are incremented.. but no other data shows up.

What am I doing wrong?

here is the rest of the php code:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
   echo '<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.<br> Thank you for your email. We will respond within 72 hours of receiving it. We hope you have a lovely day!</p>';
    }
//taken directly from my server host 

$sql = "INSERT INTO hcontact (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Address, EmailAddress, Country, Comments, SubscribetoMailingList)
VALUES ('firstname', 'lastname', 'phonenumber', 'address', 'emailaddress', 'country', 'comments', 'mailinglist')";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $connect->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. <br> Newly inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}
echo "<br>";

// define variables and set to empty values
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$fileToUpload = $_POST['fileToUpload'];
$mailinglist = $_POST['mailinglist'];

$date=date("m-d"); 
if ($date=="01-01") { 
  echo "Wishing you a very Happy New Year!"; 
}
elseif($date=="02-14"){
  echo "Happy Valentines Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="03-17"){
  echo "Happy St. Patrick's Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="04-01"){
  echo "Happy April Fools Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="05-01"){
  echo "Happy May Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="05-30"){
  echo "Happy Memorial Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="06-15"){
  echo "Happy Start of Summer!"; 
}
elseif($date=="07-04"){
  echo "Happy Independence Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="08-14"){
  echo "Happy Back To School Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="09-14"){
  echo "Happy Oktoberfest!"; 
}
elseif($date=="10-28"){
  echo "Happy Halloween!"; 
}
elseif($date=="11-25"){
  echo "Happy Thanksgiving Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="11-26"){
  echo "Happy Small Business Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="12-04"){
  echo "Happy St. Barbara's Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="12-06"){
  echo "Happy St. Nicholas Day!"; 
}
elseif($date=="12-24"){
  echo "Happy Christmas Eve!"; 
}
elseif($date=="12-25"){
  echo "Merry Christmas!"; 
}
else{
  //nothing
}

//current Date, i.e. 2017-05-17  
   echo date("Y-m-d");  
echo "<br>";
//current Time in 12 hour format, i.e. 08:50:55pm       
   echo date("h:i:sa"); 
echo "<br>";
$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $phoneErr = $addressErr = $emailaddressErr = $countryErr = $commentsErr = $mailinglistErr = "";

$email = "me@theformsemailaddress.com";
$emailSubject = "Question";

$headers = "From:$emailaddress\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br><br>

Date : $date <br>
First Name : $firstname <br>
Last Name : $lastname <br>
Phone Number : $phone <br>
Address : $address <br>
Email Address : $emailaddress <br>
Country : $country <br>
Comments : $comments <br>
Photo Submission : $fileToUpload <br>
Subscribe to Mailing List : $mailinglist <br>
EOD;

$success = mail($email, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

$theResults = <<<EOD
"Thank you. Your message has been sent and you will be contacted within 72 hours"
echo "<br>";
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo  $firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo  $lastname;
echo "<br>";
echo  $phone;
echo "<br>";
echo  $address;
echo "<br>";
echo  $emailaddress;
echo "<br>";
echo  $country;
echo "<br>";
echo  $comments;
echo "<br>";
echo  $fileToUpload;
echo "<br>";
echo  $mailinglist;
echo "<br>";
EOD;

echo "First Name:  " . $firstname . "<br>";
echo "Last Name:  " . $lastname . "<br>";
echo "Phone:  " . $phone . "<br>";
echo "Address:  " . $address . "<br>";
echo "Email Address:  " . $emailaddress . "<br>";
echo "Country:  " . $country . "<br>";
echo "Comments: " . $comments . "<br>";
echo "Photo Submission:  " . $fileToUpload . "<br>";
echo "Subscribe to Mailing List?:  " . $mailinglist . "<br>";


$db = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password");
if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$db);

$sql = "INSERT INTO hcontact (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Address, EmailAddress, Country, Comments, SubscribetoMailingList) VALUES (".
PrepSQL($varcontact-us) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varfirstname) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varlastname) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varphone) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varaddress) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varemailaddress) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varcountry) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varcomments) . ", " .
PrepSQL($varmailinglist) . ", " .

mysql_query($sql);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
    $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
}
  if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
    $lastnameErr = "Last name is required";
  } else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
    $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
}
}
  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phoneErr = "Please enter a phone number";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $addressErr = "Address is required";
  } else {
    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["emailaddress"])) {
    $emailaddressErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $emailaddress = test_input($_POST["emailaddress"]);
  if (!filter_var($emailaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailaddressErr = "Invalid email format";
}
}
  if (empty($_POST["country"])) {
    $countryERR = "please enter your country";
   } else {
   $country = test_input($_POST["country"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["comments"])) {
    $comments = "";
  } else {
    $comments = test_input($_POST["comments"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["fileToUpload"])) {
    $fileToUpload = "";
  } else {
    $fileToUpload = test_input($_POST["fileToUpload"]);
}
  if (empty($_POST["mailinglist"])) {
    $mailinglistErr = "requres a yes or no";
  } else {
    $mailinglist = test_input($_POST["mailinglist"]);
}

 function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

  if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit") 
{
$varfirstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$varlastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$varphone = $_POST['phone'];
$varaddress = $_POST['address'];
$varemailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
$varcountry = $_POST['country'];
$varcomments = $_POST['coments'];
$varmailinglist = $_POST['mailinglist'];
$errorMessage = "";
// - - - snip - - - 
}

echo "$theResults";
}




   $connect->close();
?>
```

Here is my html page info:

```
  <form name="hcontact" id="form1" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'><action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>

<p><label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name.." required><value=<?php echo $firstname;?></input>
<span class="error">*<?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span></p>

    <p><label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.." required><value=<?php echo $lastname;?></input>
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span></p>

<p><label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Your phone number.." required><value=<?php echo $phone;?></input>
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></p>

    <p><label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Your address.." required><value=<?php echo $address;?></input>
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $addressErr;?></span></p>

    <p><label for="emailaddress">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Your email address.." required><value=<?php echo $emailaddress;?></input>
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $emailaddressErr;?></span></p>

    <p><label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country" required>
      <option calue="">Select..</option>
      <option value="australia"<? if($varcountry=="australia") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Australia</option>
      <option value="canada"<? if($varcountry=="canada") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Canada</option>
  <option value="europe"<? if($varcountry=="europe") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Europe</option>
      <option value="usa"<? if($varcountry=="usa") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>USA</option>
      <option value="mars"<? if($varcountry=="mars") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Mars</option>
      <option value="jupiter"<? if($varcountry=="jupiter") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Jupiter</option>
      <option value="hell"<? if($varcountry=="hell") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Hell</option>
      <option value="heaven"<? if($varcountry=="heaven") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Heaven</option>
      <option value="purgatory"<? if($varcountry=="purgatory") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Purgatory</option>
      <option value="emeraldcity"<? if($varcountry=="emeraldcity") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>The Emerald City</option>
      <option value="myimagination"<? if($varcountry=="myimagination") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>MyImagination</option>
     <option value="mrrogers"<? if($varcountry=="mrrogers") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Mr. Roger's Neighborhood</option>
      <option value="sesamestreet"<? if($varcountry=="sesamestreet") echo(" selected=\"selected\"");?>Sesame Street</option>
    </select>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $countryErr;?></span></p>

  <p><label for="comments">Comments:</label>
  <textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="25" rows="5" placeholder="Enter comments here..." required value=<?php echo $comments;?></textarea>></p>


<p><label for="fileToUpload">Upload a photo:</label> 
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" value="<?php echo     $fileToUpload;?>" multiple/>
</p>

<p><label for="videotoupload">Upload a video:</label>
<?php echo $max_file_size_tag; ?>
<input type="file" accept="video/*" id="fileSelect" runat="server" size="50" name="filename" action="/videos/file-upload.php" multiple/></p>



<p>Would you like to join our mailing list?
  <input type="radio" id="mailinglist" name="mailinglist" <?php if     (isset($mailinglist) && $mailinglist=="yes") echo "checked";? value="yes">Yes
  <input type="radio" id="mailinglist" name="mailinglist" <?php if     (isset($mailinglist) && $mailinglist=="no") echo "checked";? value="no">No
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $mailinglistErr;?></span></input>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="SubmitBtn" id="SubmitBtn" value="Submit" formaction="../action_page.php" onclick="contact-usvalidate();" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  </form>
```

Thanks for any guidance on this I appreciate it. 
Bo dakks

Comment: You aren't supplying values from variables, instead you are supplying literal strings. You should use a mysqli_prepare and bind to avoid sql injection, and to make sure the values are quoted properly. Also, not required, but good practice, use backtics to quote column and table names.

Comment: You have error somewhere. Please see logs. At least here `$sql = "INSERT INTO hcontact....` you have 8 columns and 9 values. MySQL don't accept such query.

Comment: Plus, this variable alone `$varcontact-us` is interpreted as `varcontact` **minus** `us`. You should learn to debug.

Comment: `><action="` that also has a character your form should be complaining about. The `>` alone is terminating your form, so the action may never take place. Your code contains too many errors.

Comment: I couldn't get it to even work unless I took the action out of the sentence and made it separate.. will look at it again.  Thanks for the feedback